# Vuetify navigation drawer keeps showing itself whenever refresh the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, navigation-drawer, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a navigation drawer for my page using Vuetify. And the navigation drawer keeps showing itself whenever I refresh my page or occurs at the start of the page. Is it possible to disable it?

```
``https://codepen.io/yuisnow/pen/bJYzvz
```

I'm expecting the navigation drawer should be hidden in any case. Only shows when the user clicks the hamburger menu button but the navigation drawer keeps showing itself when I refresh my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks from 'false' in your JS.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
      return {
        sideNav: null,
      }
    },
  created () {
    this.sideNav=false;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove created hook
problem solved,
previously on your created hook you already have a value "this.sideNav=false;"
on it so it is a valid sideNav value and so drawer is activated

Comment: Noted. Will try it out